# Twitter Typeahead: How to show "Result not found" message into a DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, typeahead.js

I'm using [Twitter TypeAhead plugin 0.11](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) and i would like to display a message "*No results found*" into a DIV, however the code that i'm inserting according to the documentation is not working. I found some similar questions about, and i didn't find the correctly way to solve this:

1. [twitter bootstrap typeahead ajax example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232748/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-ajax-example)
2. [jQuery Ajax error handling, show custom exception messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377644/jquery-ajax-error-handling-show-custom-exception-messages)
3. [Twitter Typeahead with template always return only 1 row of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18009249/twitter-typeahead-with-template-always-return-only-1-row-of-data)
4. [typeahead empty template not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26029039/typeahead-empty-template-not-working)

The parameter that i'm trying to use is "**templates {empty:**". Below are the typeahead and ajax code that i'm using in my project:

HTML code:

```html
<label>Search Country</label>
   <input type="text" name="country" id="country" class="form-control input-lg" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Type Country Name" />
<div id="message"></div>
```

TypeAhead and Ajax code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#country').typeahead({
  source: function(query, result)
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"fetch.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{query:query},
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(data)
    {
     result($.map(data, function(item){
      return item;
     }));
    }

   })
  },

  templates: {
        empty: function(data){

          $('#message').text('Country not found');
        }},

 });

});
</script>
```

And finally, the php code **fetch.php** that return results to Ajax:

```
<?php
//fetch.php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
$request = ($connect, $_POST["query"]);
$query = "
 SELECT * FROM countries WHERE name LIKE '%".$request."%'
";

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

$data = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
  $data[] = $row["name"];
 }
 echo json_encode($data);
}

?>
```

All the code above works fine, but when i inserted the code below after typeahead parameter "**source**", nothing happen when i type something wrong inside input "**#country**"

```
templates: {
        empty: function(data){

          $('#message').text('Country not found');
        }},
```

In this case, is it possible to display "*No results Founds*" inside a div?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `notFound` instead of `empty`.

Also, I believe the `options` argument is required but can be `null`. So you should be calling it like this `.typeahead(null, { source: ..., templates: { notFound: ... } })`